# Create List ( of string ) from txt file in Resources [ VB .Net ]

Tags: vb.net, text, resources

i wanna create a List (Of string ) from a file stored in
    My.Resources.

The code  that i used is this:

```
Dim L As New List(Of String) From {(My.Resources.html_blu)}
```

but this doesen't works.

Anyone could help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to put the lines on the List, try this:

```
Dim L As New List(Of String)(My.Resources.html_blu.Split(Environment.NewLine()))
```

Comment: retrive an error:
    Eccezione first-chance di tipo 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll